# Python create a directory and save .txt file into it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on the school assignment using the Python Socket library.
I have server.py and client.py, and basically, I request a copy of the .txt file from client-side to server-side, and client-side needed to receive the text elements, create a new .txt file and directory to save it.

I am stuck in the file handling on the client-side.
What is the best way I can do create a directory and save .txt file into it?

```
# create a new .txt file for incoming data and save to new directory
with open(new_dir / "copied_text_file.txt", '+w') as text:
    text.write(file_text)
```

I tried this way, and it does not save in my new directory.
I appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with sockets; the data in `file_text` could have come from anywhere. Is `new_dir` an instance of `pathlib.Path`?

Comment: To create a directory, there's [os.mkdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20mkdir#os.mkdir). There's also [os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20mkdir#os.makedirs)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a path, use [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html) methods, see in particular join.

Answer (score 0):

Is the name of your new directory "new_dir"? If so the command needs to be `open("new_dir/copied_text_file.txt", "+w")`. If not and new_dir is a string of the directory use `open((new_dir + "/copied_text_file.txt"), "+w")` better yet would be to use `os.path.join(new_dir, "copied_text_file.txt")` and call open on the resulting pathname.

Answer (score 0):

`open()` takes a string as the destination for the file you're going
to be working with. You can pass it a URI just like would would use
when working on the command line.

```
import os

with open(os.path.join(new_dir / "copied_text_file.txt", '+w')) as text:
    text.write(file_text)
```

You could just concatenate with `+`,

```
with open(new_dir+'/'+ "copied_text_file.txt", '+w')) as text:
    # ...
```

However, using `+` will be lower because `path.join` lives inside
complied c code the python interpreter has an easier time running,
rather than having to do the concatenation in python which has more
overhead than CPython models.

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.join